# How to alter the default target directory ({app}) after User Info page in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I need to create a setup package that will allow multiple instances of the same application to be installed on the same PC/server. So, I wish to dynamically amend the default "install to" location after the UserInfo page has been processed.

i.e. in the `NextButtonClick` event I wish to change the value on the SelectDir wizard page when the `CurPageID=wpUserInfo`. Something like this below (which throws an exception). I'm also assuming that I can access the user name by expanding `{userinfoname}`. Any help would be appreciated.

```pascal
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  Page: TInputDirWizardPage;
begin
  case CurPageID of
    ........
    wpUserInfo:
      begin
        Page := TInputDirWizardPage(PageFromID(wpSelectDir));
        Page.Values[0] := MyAppDirFunction;
      end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the "Destination folder" box, use `WizardForm.DirEdit`:

```pascal
WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := Path;
```

See [`TWizardForm` reference](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TWizardForm).