# Support multiple installations in one Inno Setup installer

Tags: inno-setup

As explained in [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72634315/make-installer-capable-of-installing-addon-files-to-various-applications-in-inno) I would like to write an installer that has to support multiple installations into one of multiple possible applications (max. 3 different flight simulators).

I have written a correctly working customer wizard page that is shown immediately after the `wpWelcome` page and that queries from the user into what application (s)he wants to install the files. The result of the query is stored in a global variable that can be access by any function or procedure in the `[code]` section.

With this result I need to execute an application specific installation that should be independent to the other installations in one of the applications. This is required because though its the same files that are installed into one of the possible application there is no dependence between the installations in the different applications. Due to this it must be possible to install and uninstall in one application independent whether the same files are installed in the other applications.

To achieve this, global variables set up in `[Setup]` like `AppId`, `AppName`, `DefaultDirName`, etc. change depending of the selected application. Is it possible to change the global variables in `[Setup]`? Or run `[Setup]` once more after the user has made its choice in the customer wizard page? What else could I do to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: First thanks for the link concerning the 'AppId'; it answers 2/3 of my question. However the 'DefaultDirName' is not covered. The anser can be found in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43814733/how-to-alter-the-default-target-directory-app-after-user-info-page-in-inno-s/43816914#43816914